# Parse links of a JSON file und download them

Tags: ios, json, facebook

I want to create an App which parses the picture Links of a Facebook page and shows them in an iOS app (display them in tableView). But after I parsed the JSON file and added them to an array which should be downloaded nothing is displayed. 
Here's the code:

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
{
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
[super viewDidLoad];


items = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://graph.facebook.com/HuppFotografie/photos/uploaded/?fields=id,name,picture"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

connection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];

if (connection) {
    webData = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];


}

}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse    *)response
{
[webData setLength:0];
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
[webData appendData:data];
}


-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
NSLog(@"fail with error");
}

-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
NSDictionary *allDataDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:webData options:0 error:nil];
NSArray *arrayOfData = [allDataDictionary objectForKey:@"data"];

for (NSDictionary *dicton in arrayOfData) {
    NSString *picture = [dicton objectForKey:@"picture"];

    [items addObject:picture];

}



}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath   *)indexPath {
return 250.0;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
// Return the number of sections.
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
// Return the number of rows in the section.
return [items count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MyImageCell";
ImageCell *cell = (ImageCell *) [tableView   dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

if (cell == nil) {
    NSArray* topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ImageCell"  owner:self options:nil];
    for (id currentObject in topLevelObjects) {
        if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]) {
            cell = (ImageCell *)currentObject;
            break;
        }
    }
}

// Here we use the new provided setImageWithURL: method to load the web image
[cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[items      objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Placeholder.jpg"]];

cell.imageSource.text = [items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

return cell;
}
```

I really don't get why. I'm sorry if this question is stupid but I am coding just as a hobby and have not that great experience.

Comment: Did you check the values of allDataDictionary, arrayOfData and the items array in connectionDidFinishLoading?

Comment: Maybe try to reload table view at the end of 'connectionDidFinishLoading'.
Edit: Do you see any placeholder images? If not, my suggestion above should be correct.

Comment: Yes no placeholders are displayed ... So your Suggestion will be correct .. I Check it tomorrow cause I'm Not at home today. Thank you for your fast answer

Answer (score 0):

In fact your connection is asynchronous, so you just need to reload your table view programmatically to display loaded images:

-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
   {
      NSDictionary *allDataDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:webData options:0          error:nil];
      NSArray *arrayOfData = [allDataDictionary objectForKey:@"data"];

```
  for (NSDictionary *dicton in arrayOfData) {
      NSString *picture = [dicton objectForKey:@"picture"];

         [items addObject:picture];

  }

   // Just add this line, in order to force reload when all your data is arrived
   [self.tableView reloadData];   

}
```

Comment: Still Not working .. Now I tried do add links to The Array Manually ans it worked ... So maybe something is wrong with The JSON sterialization .. I think The only possible explanation why Even no placeholders are displayed is that The Array is empty ..